# SQL Server : JOIN Subquery (SELECT data from history)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got some troubles creating a SQL request.
I'll try to explain it as a simple use case.

I have two tables :

*CarOwnerHistory:*

```
SN |  Owner  |   Date
```

*Reparation*

```
CarSN |  Operation  |   ReparationDate
```

I would like to know the car owner at the time of the reparation.

I have the following request giving me the results I'm looking for but I can't GROUP BY the alias of the subquery.

```
SELECT     
a.Operation,
a.ReparationDate,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 p.Owner 
    FROM CarOwnerHistory p 
    WHERE p.SN = a.CarSN 
    AND p.[Date] < a.ReparationDate
    ORDER BY p.[Date] DESC 
) Owner
FROM Reparation a;
```

I tried to do this request with INNER JOINs but ended creating too many subqueries...

Is there any simple solution that will allow me to GROUP BY my results and "performance friendly".

Thanks !

Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT     
  a.Operation,
  a.ReparationDate,
  OwnerTable.[Owner]
FROM Reparation a
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 p.Owner as [Owner]
  FROM CarOwnerHistory p 
  WHERE p.SN = a.CarSN 
  AND p.[Date] < a.ReparationDate
  ORDER BY p.[Date] DESC 
) OwnerTable
```

Latter on you can use `OwnerTable.[Owner]` for group by as well

Comment: Well, thank you very much for the reactivity @jaydipj. It works like a charm.

Comment: If it is help you then you can mark as Ans or any other Ans

Comment: Seems I have to wait 1 minute :D